# Binary search of an array of objects, using one of the fields as the "value"

Tags: java, arrays, binary

So I'm trying to implement a binary search of an array of objects.

This is my object class:

```
private class Item<Short extends Comparable<Short>, Integer> implements Comparable<Entry<Short, Integer>> {

        public Short value;
        public Integer key;

        public Item(Short value, Integer key){
            this.value = value;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry<Short, Integer> e) {
            return (int) this.value - (int) e.value;
        }
```

Then my code to search the (already sorted) array for an Entry with value "item" is:

```
Collections.binarySearch(array, new Entry<>(item, 0));
```

However I am receiving an error saying:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that MyProject.Entry[] conforms to List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: What is the purpose of `Entry`? Why not just write `class Item implements Comparable<Item>`?